# HTML how do I insert dynamic date in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, date, text, static

I have a static webpage, nothing changes dynamically. However the client wants a date insert into text within the page. The date will always be the current daet plus one day. how do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use JavaScript and insert the date onLoad.

Take a look here for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xGDvp/

This will update the date as follows: **February 5, 2011**

Your HTML:

```
<span id="spanDate"></span>
```

Your Javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
           var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
'August','September','October','November','December'];       
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime() + (1000*3600*24));       
document.getElementById("spanDate").innerHTML = months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + " " + tomorrow.getDate()+ ", " + tomorrow.getFullYear();
    </script>
```

Comment: this inserts just the day, not the full date.

Comment: How do you want the date to be written?

Comment: full month day, year (i.e. February 4, 2011)

Comment: Updated code.  It will need an array of months to change the month to an actual month name.

Comment: I have <span id="dynDate"></span> in my code but it will not update is the javascript supposed to be in the header or body?

Comment: I've updated the code so that you can just drop it on the page.  Just copy and paste the above anywhere below your span.  It's better to put this in a function and then run it onLoad but this way is certainly the easiest way to get you going.

Comment: I've updated the code again with EXACTLY what you are looking for.  I've also included a link to a page show the sample code running.

Comment: Ok Im frustrated now, it is telling me that document.getElementByID is null even though in the "view source" I can clearly see the spanDate

Comment: Are you placing the code above or below your span?  The code, as it is written right now, requires that it be placed below the span.

Comment: I placed it below the span and the page hangs when it is trying to read google.apis, I put it above the code and I get that error

Comment: ok now it isnt hanging when I put it below the tag, however it is showing last month LOL

Comment: Actually it is hanging only in FireFox and says its reading ajax.googleapis.com

Comment: Try putting the code inside a function, for example WriteDate(), and set the onLoad property of the Body tag like <body onLoad="WriteDate()">

Comment: Last month?  Are you copying the Javascript code as it is written?  The code (as you can see in the example page) calculates tomorrow's date.  You must have mistyped something if it is showing a different month.

Comment: k thanks it is working perfectly I appreciate all the help everyone

Answer (score 3):

<sup>**Downvoters**: Note that the tag "javascript" was added *after* this answer was given.</sup>

You could use Server Side Includes (SSI), if your server supports them.

If your server is Apache, you could, for example, put the following element into your HTML page to output a current date + 1 day:

```
<pre>
<!--#exec cmd="date -v +1d '+DATE: %Y-%m-%d'" -->
</pre>
```

Assuming today is 2011-02-05, you'll have the following output on your page in browser:

```
...
DATE: 2011-02-06
...
```

To output the full weekday name, you can use `date -v +1d '+DATE: %A %d, %Y'`, which gives you `DATE: Sunday 06, 2011`.

---

Further reading:

- article [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) at Wikipedia
- [Apache Tutorial: Introduction to Server Side Includes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html)
- [`date(1)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=date&sektion=1) manual page at FreeBSD.org

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = initDate;
function initDate() {
     var dayName = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday","Saturday");
     var monName = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
     var now = new Date();
     var dtString = dayName[now.getDay()] + ", " + monName[now.getMonth()] + " " + now.getDate();
     document.getElementById("dtField"). innerHTML = dtString;
}
```

[Source](http://www.icoders.org/2012/06/how-display-current-date-web-page-using-javascript.html)

Answer (score 1):

If your not opposed to PHP, then you could do something like this... Also Tizag..
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpdate.php

```
<?php
$todayPlusADay = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+1, date("y"));
echo "Todays Date Plus One Day (Tomorrow) ".date("m/d/y", $todayPlusADay); 
?>
```

Quick search for "php echo date + 1 day" produced that little diddy :) That could certainly be expanded upon to any extent just about.

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript to insert the date somewhere in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);

//insert it via jquery
$('#displayDate').html((newDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + newDate.getDate() + '/' + newDate.getFullYear());

//or insert it via javascript
document.getElementById('displayDate').innerHTML = (newDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + newDate.getDate() + '/' + newDate.getFullYear();

</script>
```

and the html:

```
<span id="displayDate"></span>
```

test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/9xWUT/

Comment: Would I do this on a span tag?

Comment: You could do it in any element. Yes you could do it in a span. see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I recommend XDate because it will save a lot of typing. Also, please don't use innerHTML, it's such a bad habit. I just did the same on a web page and the key thing was to use inline javascript beneath the tag you are updating although you can use 'onload' as well.

In the page I add the tag and put in some default info just because:

```
<p>Today is <span id="todays_date" style="font-style: italic;">November 1, 2015</span></p>
```

With this below that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var today = new XDate();

  document.getElementById("todays_date").innerHTML = "";

  document.getElementById("todays_date").appendChild(document.createTextNode(today.toString("MMMM d, yyyy")));
</script>
```

NB: I do use innerHTML to quickly obliterate nested tags rather than a recursive "delete all children" because that's in a different library and not pertinent to this example.

See http://arshaw.com/xdate/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in javascript.
http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptdate.php

Then you can add for example a span tag in your text, and insert the date with javascript.
If you can use jQuery, you can do something like:

html:

```
<p>Tomorrow: <span class="tomorrow"></span></p>
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var date = new Date()
    $(".tomorrow").html(date.getDate() + 1) // you'll have to search how to format the date
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in my way this is below

HTML:

< asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='' >

JavaScript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function date_time() {
    var dt = new Date();
    document.getElementById('<%=Label1.ClientID%>').innerHTML = dt;
    setTimeout(function () { date_time(); }, 1000);
}
date_time();
```