# How do I pass the value of an input type time to a Date object?

Tags: javascript, html, time

This function converts time to 12hr format, credits to a contributor on Stack Overflow for this function:

**JS**

```
function ampm(date) {
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // 0 should be 12
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes; // if minutes less than 10, add a 0 in front of it ie: 6:6 -> 6:06
    var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
    document.getElementById('time').value = strTime;
    return strTime;
}

////This is how the value of the time input is supposed to be displayed in 12 hr format
_("display_time").innerHTML = ampm(new Date());
```

**HTML**

```
<!--This is the input field where a user selects a time-->
<input id="time" placeholder="Time" type="time" name="time" />




<!--This is where the value of the time input is supposed to be displayed in 12 hr format-->>
<span id="display_time"></span>
```

My question is how do I get the value of the time input field to be displayed on the span tag in 12hr format. This code is semi-working.

It displays the time in 12hr format but only displays the current time. The flow chart would be something like, user selects time in time input -> some JS to convert to 12hr format -> display as 12hr format in span tag. Any advice or suggestions?

Comment: To be honest, it would seem like you are complicating your life. There are plenty of stackoverflow questions regarding time and date objects proposing simpler solutions. You just have to search a bit.

Comment: How are you planning to let the user to "select time in time input"? What format is that time(string? time? timestamp?)

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904667/html-how-do-i-insert-dynamic-date-in-webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use `Date` and its methods the input is a `String` so you better use `.split(":")` method and you will get the `hours` and `minutes` values directly.

Then just test if their values are lower than `10` add a leading `0` and if the `hours` is higher than `12` use `pm` suffix or use `am` otherwise.

This is a live DEMO using onchange event of the time input with its value as parameter `onchange="ampm(this.value)` :

```js
function ampm(time) {

  console.log(time);
  if (time.value !== "") {
    var hours = time.split(":")[0];
    var minutes = time.split(":")[1];
    var suffix = hours >= 12 ? "pm" : "am";
    hours = hours % 12 || 12;
    hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;

    var displayTime = hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix;
    document.getElementById("display_time").innerHTML = displayTime;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--This is the input field where a user selects a time-->
<input id="time" placeholder="Time" type="time" name="time" onchange="ampm(this.value)" />
<span id="display_time"></span>
```

Comment: What does the '0' mean in var hours = time.split(":")[0] ? Same with the '1' in var minutes?

Comment: @ArvinFlores these are indexes, because split gives an array as result so with `[0]` we get the first element and `[1]` we get the second one.

Comment: Ok. In var suffix, shouldnt it be >= 12 instead of just >12? Since itll go from 11:59 am to 12:00am instead of 12:00 pm?

Answer (score 3):

Your input value will be a string, not a date.  I've set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shy4a5b3/) where I've modified your javascript to work on a string.

```
$('#time').on('change', function() {
    var date = $('#time').val().split(':');

    var hours = date[0];
    var minutes = date[1];

    $('#display_time').text(ampm(hours, minutes));
});

function ampm(hours, minutes) {
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    hours = hours % 12 || 12;
    minutes = minutes || 0;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
    return hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do it

```
function showTime() {
    //Grab the time and split into hrs and mins
    var time = document.getElementById("time");
    if ( time.value === "")  {
        document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = "";
        return false;
    }
    var hrs = time.value.split(":")[0];
    var mins = time.value.split(":")[1];
    var newTime = ampm(hrs, mins);
    document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = newTime;
}

function ampm(hrs, mins) {
    return ( hrs % 12 || 12 ) + ":" + mins + (( hrs >= 12 ) ? "PM" : "AM" );
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cpd44d43/5/) is a an example. `showTime()` just needs to be ran onchange of the time input.

Comment: @RobG That would work except you still need a separate statement for 12 as when it's greater than 12 we need to remove 12 to represent a 12 hour clock

Comment: @RobG I've made an edit. It is a little more elegant, thanks

Comment: `(function(h,m){return(h%12||12)+':'+m+(h<12?'am':'pm')}.apply([],'13:08'.split(':')))`